# What is No such destination in stripe?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments

I am trying  to transfer amount from 1 stripe account to another stripe account but I am getting this error "No such destination:".

I tried to add different client ids. But it isn't working.

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('APP Key');

$transfer =  \Stripe\Transfer::create([
    "amount" => 400,
    "currency" => "usd",
    "destination" => "ca_FtG3t5**********",
    "transfer_group" => "ORDER_95"
]);
return $transfer;
```

I  want this to transfer amount to other stripe account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"No such destination"` means the account you are trying to transfer to does not exist, or is not connected to your account.

Most Stripe accounts are in the format of `acct_xxxyyyzzz`, the id you have here `ca_xxxyyyyzz` does not look like an Stripe account id. Find the accounts connected to yours [here](https://dashboard.stripe.com/connect/accounts/overview).